# How to drop a row by index from my pandas data-frame to prevent them appearing my my bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using df.drop however when I run my code I'm still seeing the "total" on row index 10 in my plot. I want this removed.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryan-j-hope/Shielding-models/master/2020%20Uk%20Population%20By%20Age%20Demographics.csv", encoding='UTF')

df.drop([10])

print(df)

ag = df["Age Group"]

pop = df["Population (%)"]

plt.bar(ag, pop)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `df = df.drop([10])`

Comment: `df.drop()` will not change the original dataframe, instead it creates a copy. If you want to make changes to original dataframe use inplace=True option. So, your drop command should look like this `df.drop([10], inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need brackets. Also, you need to specify inplace

```
df.drop(10, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.drop([10])` creates a copy of `df` with the row dropped.  Try assigning it to a new DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.drop([10])
```

then extract the columns from `df2`.  Or use the `inplace` argument to permanently modify `df`:

```
df.drop([10], inplace=True)
```

Comment: and thank you for a brilliant user name.  brought light to my day!

Answer (score 0):

Make a small change in your code. Write df.drop(10,inplace = True) while dropping.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.read_csv ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ryan-j-hope/Shielding-models/master/2020%20Uk%20Population%20By%20Age%20Demographics.csv", encoding='UTF')

    df.drop(10,inplace = True)

    print(df)

    ag = df["Age Group"]

    pop = df["Population (%)"]

    plt.bar(ag, pop)

    plt.show()
```